# Node JS MSQL cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

i wanna check if user is existing in the database but I got this error when I add results.length:

(node:12124) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

**This is the code:**

```
const mysql = require('mysql')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

exports.register = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);

    const { name, email, password, passwordConfirm } = req.body;

    db.query('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ?', [email], async (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }

        if (results.length > 0) {
            return res.render('register', {
                message: 'That email is already in use'
            })
        } else if (password !== passwordConfirm) {
            return res.render('register', {
                message: 'Passwords do not match'
            });
        }

        let hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 8);
        console.log(hashedPassword);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems pretty straightforward... If the user doesn't exist, `results` is undefined, so your condition should not check for `results.length` but instead:

```
if (results !== undefined) {
  return res.render('register', {
    message: 'That email is already in use'
  })
}
```